# MS Access: Programmatically adding button/page to a navigation form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using MS Access 2010, I need to generate the NavigationButtons of a Navigation Control at Form_Load time (or similar.)  (To be clear, this isn't a tab control nor a ribbon nor a menu.)  The use case is, there are a variable number of forms and reports that need to be added to the Navigation Control at run time.  We won't know how exactly many, or which, forms will need to be added, so they need to be added dynamically in code.  Is this possible with a Navigation Control?  I can find no reference to achieving this.

My instinct was something like:

```
Me.NavigationControl0.AddButton("Report X")
```

But no such 'AddButton' method exists... or any other combination of machinations or configurations that will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`CreateControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237827%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Note that the form must be open in **Design view** to use this. You can find many examples on the net, e.g. [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/38087-adding-controls-dynamicly.html).

If this doesn't work for you, and if you have an upper limit of needed buttons, you can create the maximum number manually, and at runtime hide as many as you don't need. Making buttons `.Visible=False` and changing their `.Caption` can be done in Form view.